# keytool.exe is not valid for Win32 application for obtaining a Google Maps Android API Key

Tags: java, android, window, keytool

when ever i try to run following commands its give me this error **keytool.exe is not valid for Win32 application**

1:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin>keytool -list -alias
>   androiddebugkey -keystore
>   “C:\Users\Jani.android\debug.keystore.keystore” -storepass android
>   -keypass android

2:

> keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey 
>   -keystore "C:\Users\Jani.android\debug.keystore.keystore" 
>   -storepass android -keypass android

im using window 7(64bit)any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you check what is the size of keytool.exe in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin?

Comment: @RaghavSood its size is 14.4 KB **(14,760 bytes)**

Comment: Try running keytool -list -keystore "<path to keystone (with quotes)>"

Answer (score 0):

There are three reasons why this would happen:

1. During your install of the JDK, keytool.exe did not install properly. If this is try, then it's size will be 0kB (rare)
2. I see that you are using JDK7. The Android tools are known to have issues with it. Installing JDK6 should fix the problem (common)
3. You might be using a 64bit version of the JDK. Try uninstalling the existing JDK and reinstalling a 32 bit version

Generally, fixing the above 3 should solve this problem.

Comment: im getting still same error , i tried step 2 and and 3. recently im try 32bit jdk and same window appear what im doing wrong :/

Comment: Did you use a 32 bit JDK 6, after uninstalling the old JDK? Have you added the new one to your PATH variable?

Comment: yes i did all i get jdk from here **http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u31-download-1501634.html**

Comment: i add variable in this way **C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin;D:\androidsdk\tools\**